# TextBox/Grid overlapping ComboBox entries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and I wrote some code for Windows Phone 8.1 Apps in C#. Now I've got a little problem with the layout in XAML with grids.

Elements in grids should be ordered/layered in the order in the code, but this didn't work for me. I've got two grids in a grid and the comboboxlist of the first grid is overlapped by the other grid/textblock. I tried to rearrange the grid in XAML, but that also did not solved the problem.

[overlapping image from the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZKa0.jpg)

In this image there should be 2 more items in the open combobox list, but those are overlapped by the grid below it.

Here is the code snippet:

```
<Grid Margin="0, 50, 0, 0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="115"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="80"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="115"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Third Row-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource StandardAppHeaderTextBlock}"
                   Text="Woche:"/>
        <ComboBox Name="WochenComboBox"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Style="{StaticResource StandardAppComboBox}"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Style="{StaticResource StandardAppHeaderTextBlock}"
                   Text="Ort:"/>
        <TextBox Name="OrtTextBox"
                 Grid.Column="1"
                 Style="{StaticResource StandardAppTextBox}"/>
    </Grid>

    <!--Second Row-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0"
                   Style="{StaticResource StandardAppHeaderTextBlock}"
                   Text="Stunde:"/>
        <ComboBox Name="StundenZeitenComboBox"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Style="{StaticResource StandardAppComboBox}"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Einstellung, Converter={StaticResource EinstellungsStundenToComboBoxListConverter}}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Value"                         
                  SelectionChanged="StundenZeitenComboBox_SelectionChanged"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Style="{StaticResource StandardAppHeaderTextBlock}"
                   Text="Veranstaltungsart:"/>
        <ComboBox Name="VeranstaltungsartComboBox"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Style="{StaticResource StandardAppComboBox}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

What should I use/do to remove this overlpapping.

Comment: Is there a reason you've chosen grids over using a stack panel? I personally would stick all those elements in a stack panel.

Comment: No, there isn't a reason why I chose the grids. Would stack panel solve my problem. I belive I read something that panel have a ZIndex property to set the layer of an element.

Answer (score 0):

Use stack panels. Items inside a stack panel will not overlap.

```
<Grid>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="115" />
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="80" />
        <RowDefinition Height="115" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>

      <!--Third Row-->
      <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
          <TextBlock Text="Woche:" />
          <ComboBox Name="WochenComboBox" Grid.Column="0" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
          <TextBlock Text="Ort:" />
          <TextBox Name="OrtTextBox" Grid.Column="1" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Grid>

      <!--Second Row-->
      <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
          <TextBlock Text="Stunde:" />
          <ComboBox Name="StundenZeitenComboBox" Grid.Column="0" DisplayMemberPath="Value" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
         <TextBlock Text="Veranstaltungsart:" />
         <ComboBox Name="VeranstaltungsartComboBox" Grid.Column="1" />
       </StackPanel>
     </Grid>
    </Grid>
```